# Are self-answer questions still allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, answers, self-answering

Shortly put I had a mechanics question about [infinity-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinity-rpg)  regarding the stealth system that was not immediately clear. I figured out the solution eventually within the book, but thought it might make a good question and answer on the site for anyone else using the system since there are not a lot of public resources for it.

We did a lot of this kind of thing for the 5e release leadup for D&D 5e and I've certainly posted questions and then a week later come back and self-answered. Just checking to see if it was okay to explicitly do so in this case from the beginning.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Absolutely! There hasn't been a change in policy and we still do it (some of us more than others:) )

Answer (score 23):

## Self Answers to questions are good

Across Stack Exchange, there's always been a stigma against self-answered questions due to the perception that this is intended to function as a kind of Reputation Farming. I don't agree with that perception, both from a theoretical perspective, and from the practical perspective of observing that Self-Answered questions often do worse, in terms of overall Reputation issued, than other questions (because of the stigma). So that is an open issue in the community.

However, the official stance of the network, and of this site specifically, is that [it is okay, and even encouraged, to try to provide answers to your own questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), and I believe that is the correct stance to take. The purpose of sites like this is to try to help people find answers to questions they might have, and if people provide self-answers to their own questions, it only means that future visitors who encounter the same problem will have a resource to look to to resolve their problem. That's a good thing.

I will say, from personal experience, to observe a few important recommendations; though these aren't rules, and you're not obligated (formally or informally) to follow them:

- Self-Answered posts usually accrue a few downvotes in their first appearance. If the post (and answer!) are good, these will usually get balanced out quickly. So don't get defensive; this is just the existing stigma against these questions, and you can't really fight that, other than by making the merit of your post as obvious as possible
- Try to focus on making the question + answer as good-looking as possible. Since you know that whatever answer you're providing is a solution to the problem you're facing, you have an opportunity to tailor them both to make sure the problem is well defined and the answer is a comprehensive response to it

Again: not rules, just suggestions based on my experience providing answers to my own questions.

Comment: Accepting your own answer also decreases the visibility of your question; a question with an accepted answer is likely to get less views since it displays differently on the main page and also doesn't enter the unanswered questions section even if the answer isn't yet upvoted.

Comment: You can't accept your own answer until 48h has passed, which is generally the time space where most of the (up)voting happens anyway.

Comment: @Someone_Evil I wasn't aware of that, is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @Xirema 2nd bullet point: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Someone_Evil Well there it is. I've removed that bulletpoint, since it's pretty much invalidated.

Comment: I'd add that asking questions has an explicit "answer your own question" check box, allowing you to post an answer at the exact same time as a question. So, while site policies vary, official Stack Exchange policy is firmly in favor.